# Azure: Is it possible to use HTTPS on non-ms VMs?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Here´s what we try to do:
We try to run several App Servers with Meteor and Mongo DB Servers on Azure VMs. We have them bundled in one cloud service with Endpoint sets that balance the load.

We setting them up via the Management Console (Ubuntu VMs) and then deploy Meteor and the content via Meteor Up.

Now we want to do HTTPS. Initially we thought that is handled by the LoadBalancer by mapping an external port 443 to the internal port 80 as there are options to upload Certificates.

It seems there is no option to configure that this way except for deployments using Visual Studio (and those seem to have to use at least some Web roles).

Here is where we struggle:
Using HTTPS seems to be tied to deploying an App developed in visual studio and/or on Windows VMs?

That´s the question:
Is it possible to use load balanced HTTPS on szure with Linux VMs?

PS: This is the Article that made me think the Load Balancer might does SSL encryption by itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff795779.aspx

Comment: I can personally say we've done this with nginx acting as a SSL proxy (gunicorn serving a Python app). I wouldn't map it to port 80 though, as HTTP is not the same protocol as HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the load balancer of Azure would only spread the traffic to the instances internal endpoint, and **do not** encrypt the traffic in SSL. (see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/)

Even for the deployment using Visual Studio, I believe the mechanism behind is also the IIS on each web role encrypting the traffic, but not the load balancer job.

So, you should add SSL on the web server of each VMs such as using nginx.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was confused by some Azure Articles that make it seem like the load balancer / Endpoint config does SSL itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff795779.aspx